# How to set focus listener to center of edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, focuslistener

How can I set the focus listener to center of edittext so that when we input data, it starts appearing from the middle of the edittext and extends to the left and right simultaneously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

design your `EditText` like this then text comes from the center..

this tag is used to center the text..`android:gravity="center"`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="your text" />
```